# Sequelize M:N Association - "TypeError: Members.belongsToMany is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js

I have two tables in a MySQL schema, 'members' and 'events', which share a many-to-many relationship.  I am attempting to model that relationship using Sequelize via a junction table containing a member_id and an event_id (which correspond to columns in the Members and Events tables respectively) and an event_date - the date when an event is attended by many members.

I am following the guidance in the Sequelize 'Advanced Associations' section ([link](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/)), but am getting an error when my node.js server attempts to start, as follows:

```
    Members.belongsToMany(models.Events, { through: 'member_events' })
            ^
    TypeError: Members.belongsToMany is not a function
```

I'm really stuggling to understand what specifically this means and how I can address the issue.  The following is my code for the three models in question:

**memberEvents.js**

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Members = require('../models/members')
      const Events = require('../models/events')
      
      const MemberEvents = sequelize.define(
        "MemberEvents",
        {
          member_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
    
          event_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
    
          event_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
        },
        { tableName: "member_events" }
      );
    
            Members.belongsToMany(Events, { through: 'member_events' })
            Events.belongsToMany(Members, { through: 'member_events' })
    
    
      return MemberEvents;
    };
```

**Members.js**

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      //Below creates the member table in the schema
      const Members = sequelize.define(
        "Members",
        {
          member_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
    
          forename: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
            allowNull: false,
          },
    
          surname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
            allowNull: false,
          },
    
          date_of_birth: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false,
          },
    
          address_1: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
            allowNull: false,
          },
    
          address_2: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
          },
    
          address_3: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
          },
    
          address_4: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
          },
    
          address_5: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
          },
    
          postcode: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(12),
            allowNull: false,
          },
    
          directions: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT("long"),
          },
    
          mobile_phone: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(12),
          },
    
          email_address: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
          },
    
          key_safe_code: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(8),
          },
    
          next_of_kin_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(70),
          },
    
          next_of_kin_phone: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(12),
          },
    
          next_of_kin_local: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(33),
          },
    
          next_of_kin_relationship: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
          },
    
          doctor_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
          },
    
          initial_medical_conditions: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT("long"),
          },
    
          deceased: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
          },
    
          normally_escorted: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(3),
          },
    
          blue_badge_holder: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(3),
          },
    
          medical_equipment: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
          },
        },
        { tableName: "Member" }
      );
    
    
      return Members;
    };
```

**Events.js**

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      //Below creates the event table in the schema
      const Events = sequelize.define(
        "Events",
        {
          event_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
    
          event_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(70),
            allowNull: false,
          },
    
          staff_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
          },
        },
        { tableName: "Events" }
      );
    
    
      return Events;
    };
```

Comment: Looks like there's no code that fires the error. Maybe you're calling to `models.Events` in some other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When separating your Sequelize models into separate imports, use the `associate` function to access the models to make these associations. You also don't need to import the other models into each other.

Something along these lines should work:

**TableA.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const TableA = sequelize.define('table_a', {
    foobar: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  TableA.associate = function(models) {
    TableA.belongsTo(models.TableB, { through: 'table_c' });
  };
  return TableA;
};
```

**TableB.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const TableB = sequelize.define('table_b', {
    fazbaz: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  TableB.associate = function(models) {
    TableB.belongsTo(models.TableA, { through: 'table_c' });
  };
  return TableB;
};
```

Comment: Hi Wes, that works in terms of resolving the issue with the error message.  However, my table definition in memberEvents.js is not being applied: Sequelize generates a member_events table with columns createdAt, updatedAt, EventEventId and MemberMemberID.  I can re-code elsewhere to take into account the fact that the EventEventId and MemberMemberId column names it generated are different to what I planned, but it is entirely missing the event_date column.  This issue was why I tried putting the associate logic in the memberEvents.js file.  What is the correct way to resolve this?

Comment: This model and it's associations don't have bearing on the actual table creation which is taken care of by a `migration`. Did you look at your migration for those tables to make sure all the columns are there?

Comment: hmm.  I haven't created or used any migration related code - unless it is created automatically by Sequelize and I'm just unaware of it (I don't have any files or folders related to migrations in my project folder). For all the other tables I've created so far (none of which involved many-to-many relationships), if the table didn't already exist, it was created when my node server started, based on the content of my model files.
Am I understanding correctly, that many-to-many relationships are a special scenario where a migration file is mandatory?

Comment: Got it. Are you Sequelize v6? I'll test out what I provided and see what's going on.

Comment: I just realized unless you have some `Model.sync()` specified or `sequelize.sync({ force: true });` specified, Sequelize won't update your table for you when you change your model. Anytime I've made changes to a database using Sequelize ORM, it's through migrations which contain an `up` and `down` function of my change so it can be easily reverted. I've used v5 mostly but don't see that behavior has changed. See if this helps get your table matching your model --- https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization

Comment: I got it working - I dropped all three tables, then just created member_event using the memberEvent.js model, which created the table with all desired columns.  Once that was created, I then created the members and events tables with their respective model files and the belongsToMany code too.  All seems to have worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i.e. I think the second issue I faced was timing related/order of table creation.